Atmega328p stops mid instruction when in interrupt
I want to make a basic temperature/humidity/CO2 controller with a SDC41 sensor and i want to use an INT0 interrupt to switch from normal controller mode to menu mode to change set values. When i press the button it starts the first instruction in the interrupt to print "interrupt start" but stops at "in".
I have tried all of the options of falling edge, rising edge, low state interrupt, all with the same result
Any ideas why or how to solve?
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SensirionI2CScd4x.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);
SensirionI2CScd4x scd4x;
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define PIN0 0
#define PIN1 1
#define PIN2 2
#define PIN3 3
#define PIN4 4
#define PIN5 5
#define PIN6 6
#define PIN7 7

uint16_t setCO2=1000;
float setTemp=20.0f;
float setRH=85.0f;


ISR(INT0_vect)
{
  SREG &= ~(1<<SREG_I); 
  Serial.println("interrupt start");
  int16_t i=0;
  bool setting = false;
  lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
  

  
  while(PIND & 1<<PIN2 == 1<<PIN2){
      setting = false;
      if(PIND & 1<<PIN5 == 0)
        i++;
      if(PIND & 1<<PIN4 == 0)
        i--;
      
      lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
      if(PIND & 1<<PIN3 == 0)
      {
        setting = true;
        delay(1000);
        switch (i%3){
            case 0:
              lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
              while(PIND & 1<<PIN3 == 1<<PIN3){
                
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN5 == 0){
                    setCO2 += 10;
                    lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                    delay(100);
                } 
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN4 == 0){
                    setCO2 -= 10;
                    lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                    delay(100);
                }
              }
              break;

            case 1:
              lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
              while(PIND & 1<<PIN3 == 1<<PIN3){
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN5 == 0){
                  setTemp += 0.1;
                  lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                  delay(100);
                }
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN4 == 0){
                  setTemp -= 0.1;
                  lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                  delay(100);
                }
              }
              break;


            case 2:
              lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
              while(PIND & 1<<PIN3 == 1<<PIN3){
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN5 == 0){
                  setRH += 1;
                  lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                  delay(100);
                }
                if(PIND & 1<<PIN4 == 0){
                  setRH -= 1;
                  lcdprintmenu(setting, i);
                  delay(100);
                }
              }
              break;

        }
        

      }

  }


  SREG |= 1<<SREG_I;
}


void lcdprintmenu(bool setting, int16_t i){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Set CO2 = ");
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(setCO2);
  lcd.setCursor(15,0);
  lcd.print("ppm");
  
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Set Temp = ");
  lcd.setCursor(12,1);
  lcd.print(setTemp);
  lcd.setCursor(16,1);
  lcd.print("C");

  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("Set Umid = ");
  lcd.setCursor(12,1);
  lcd.print(setRH);
  lcd.setCursor(16,1);
  lcd.print("%");

  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  if (setting = false)
    lcd.print("Select  V  Inapoi ->");
  else
    lcd.print("Inapoi  V");

  lcd.setCursor(19,i%3);
  lcd.print("*");
}

void printlcd(uint16_t co2, float temperature, float humidity){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("CO2 = ");
  lcd.setCursor(6,0);
  lcd.print(co2);
  lcd.setCursor(11,0);
  lcd.print("ppm");

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Temperatura = ");
  lcd.setCursor(14,1);
  lcd.print(temperature);
  lcd.setCursor(18,1);
  lcd.print("C");

  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("Umiditate = ");
  lcd.setCursor(12,2);
  lcd.print(humidity);
  lcd.setCursor(16,2);
  lcd.print("%");

  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("Seteaza parametrii >");
}
void setup() {

  SREG |= 1<<SREG_I;
  //HI-LO INTERRUPT ON PIN 0
  EICRA = (0<<ISC11)|(0<<ISC10)|(1<<ISC01)|(0<<ISC00);
  EIMSK = (0<<INT1)|(1<<INT0);
  EIFR = (0<<INTF1)|(0<<INTF0);
  DDRD = 0x00;
  PORTD = 0xFF;

  //outputs
  DDRB = 0xFF;
  PORTB = 0x00;
  
  Serial.begin(57600);      
  lcd.init();       
  lcd.backlight();  
  //init of lcd screen

  Wire.begin();

  uint16_t error;
  char errorMessage[256];

  scd4x.begin(Wire);

  // stop potentially previously started measurement
  error = scd4x.stopPeriodicMeasurement();
  if (error) {
      Serial.print("Error trying to execute stopPeriodicMeasurement(): ");
      errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
      Serial.println(errorMessage);
  }

  uint16_t serial0;
  uint16_t serial1;
  uint16_t serial2;
  error = scd4x.getSerialNumber(serial0, serial1, serial2);
  if (error) {
      Serial.print("Error trying to execute getSerialNumber(): ");
      errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
      Serial.println(errorMessage);
  } else {
      printSerialNumber(serial0, serial1, serial2);
  }

  // Start Measurement
  error = scd4x.startPeriodicMeasurement();
  if (error) {
      Serial.print("Error trying to execute startPeriodicMeasurement(): ");
      errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
      Serial.println(errorMessage);
  }

  Serial.println("Waiting for first measurement... (5 sec)");
}

void loop() {

  uint16_t error;
  char errorMessage[256];

  delay(100);

  // Read Measurement & afisare
  uint16_t co2 = 0;
  float temperature = 0.0f;
  float humidity = 0.0f;
  bool isDataReady = false;

  error = scd4x.getDataReadyFlag(isDataReady);
  if (error) {
      Serial.print("Error trying to execute getDataReadyFlag(): ");
      errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
      Serial.println(errorMessage);
      return;
  }
  if (!isDataReady) {
      return;
  }



  error = scd4x.readMeasurement(co2, temperature, humidity);
  if (error) {
      Serial.print("Error trying to execute readMeasurement(): ");
      errorToString(error, errorMessage, 256);
      Serial.println(errorMessage);
  } else if (co2 == 0) {
      Serial.println("Invalid sample detected, skipping.");
  } 
  else {
    printlcd(co2,temperature,humidity);
    //Fresh air exchange
    if(co2>setCO2+200)
      PORTB|=1<<PIN0;
    else if(co2<setCO2-100)
      PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN0);
    //if fresh air is going
    if(PINB & (1<<PIN0) == 1<<PIN0){
      //hot
      if(temperature<setTemp-1)
        PORTB|=1<<PIN1;
      else if(temperature>setTemp+1)
        PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN1);
      
      //cold
      if(temperature>setTemp+2)
        PORTB|=1<<PIN2;
      else if(temperature<setTemp)
        PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN2);
      }
      //if no fresh air not hot 
    else{
      PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN1);
      PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN2);
    }

    if(humidity<setRH-10)
      PORTB|=1<<PIN3;
    else if (humidity>setRH+5)
      PORTB &= ~(1<<PIN3);
  }
}



You can't Serial.println from within an interrupt. The Serial code itself requires the use of interrupts, and calling it from within another interrupt prevents that from working.

Interrupts interrupt the control flow in between machine code instructions, not high-level language instructions. Your expectation seems odd.

please do not post pictures of text at this site ... post the text instead

move all code from ISR into the loop() block ... insert interruptOccured = true; into the ISR ... use the state of interruptOccured to execute the moved code

An interrupt service routine (ISR) will disable further interrupts during its execution, and re-enable them as it exits, to prevent interruption of the servicing of the interruption. Consequently, you must do nothing inside an ISR that depends on interrupts to function correctly, such as Serial.println().
Instead, your ISR should be in-and-out as quickly as possible; only flagging state somehow. This change of state should be processed in the main loop, not inside the ISR.
For instance, if you have keys or buttons in your circuit, you might implement a FIFO queue to store key-presses, and the role of the ISR would be only to respond to a physical key-press, "push" a corresponding byte into that queue, then exit. It would be inside the main loop where queue content is processed, by "popping" newly arrived queue data, processing it accordingly.
For a simple pin-change ISR that should invoke a menu, you wouldn't need a whole queue, just a flag, and perhaps your code might resemble this:
#define MODE_NORMAL 0
#define MODE_MENU 1

int current_mode = MODE_NORMAL;

void ISR(INT0_vect) {
    current_mode = MODE_MENU
}

void loop() {
    if (current_mode == MODE_MENU) {
        // do menu stuff
        current_mode = MODE_NORMAL;
    }
    if (current_mode == MODE_NORMAL) {
        // do normal stuff
    }
}


Chat GPT suggested this, i tried it, same results

@StefanManolescu what results?

after further testing, i realised that you were right, even when running the routine from the ISR in main loop i was disabling all interrupts with the SREG register to use the menu properly which was messing with the Serial.print and lcdprint and delay functions. Changing the EIMSK register to only disable INT0 interrupt was the way to go about this issue. Thanks

Use the interrupt only for what is strictly needed for your real time specs.
You need to define how frequent you need the interrupt to be and perform within the interrupt only what is needed within this time. The processing time of this routine needs to fit in the interrupt period.
How frequently you need to update the screen? How frequently is the data sampled? Those two numbers match? Do you need serial communication within the ISR? Likely not, so just put the data in a circular buffer and handle it (filter it) outside the ISR, updating the screen.
Does the control need to be performed within the ISR? At which frequency?

I want to use an INT0 interrupt to switch from normal controller mode to menu mode

Why?
Arduino's documentation should be more clear about this (although forum messages about usage inside ISRs are easy to find), but this part, at the end of Serial.write documentation hints about the problem:

Serial transmission is asynchronous. If there is enough empty space in the transmit buffer, Serial.write() will return before any characters are transmitted over serial. If the transmit buffer is full then Serial.write() will block until there is enough space in the buffer.


Problem
When the Serial module uses a hardware UART on the chip. A println() eventually reaches the HardwareSerial module of the Arduino library which has this snippet:
https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/c8c514c9a19602542bc32c7033f48fecbbda4401/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L255
  // If the output buffer is full, there's nothing for it other than to 
  // wait for the interrupt handler to empty it a bit
  while (i == _tx_buffer_tail) {
    if (bit_is_clear(SREG, SREG_I)) {
      // Interrupts are disabled, so we'll have to poll the data
      // register empty flag ourselves. If it is set, pretend an
      // interrupt has happened and call the handler to free up
      // space for us.
      if(bit_is_set(*_ucsra, UDRE0))
    _tx_udr_empty_irq();
    } else {
      // nop, the interrupt handler will free up space for us
    }
  }

And as you may notice, there is no code to actually release this while loop when using interrupts. This is handled by the ISR:
https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/c8c514c9a19602542bc32c7033f48fecbbda4401/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L89C1-L96C13
/* Transmit data register empty */
void HardwareSerial::_tx_udr_empty_irq(void)
{
  // If interrupts are enabled, there must be more data in the output
  // buffer. Send the next byte
  unsigned char c = _tx_buffer[_tx_buffer_tail];
  _tx_buffer_tail = (_tx_buffer_tail + 1) % SERIAL_TX_BUFFER_SIZE;

  *_udr = c;

When you call a print function from within an ISR you encounter a problem. The ATmega with it's classic AVR architecture, by default, does not support nested interrupts.
This will mean that the interrupt flag for the the TX_UDR_EMPTY is set, but the code will no run until the active interrupt returns. Which it won't, because it's stuck in the while loop waiting for something that only happens inside that the other interrupt.
Welcome to deadlock.
You can force nested interrupts this by re-enabling the I-bit inside one. As stated in the manual:

When an interrupt occurs, the global interrupt enable I-bit is cleared and all interrupts are disabled. The user software can
write logic one to the I-bit to enable nested interrupts. All enabled interrupts can then interrupt the current interrupt routine.
The I-bit is automatically set when a return from interrupt instruction – RETI – is executed.

But that has dangerous side effects! There is no NVIC (Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller) that manages which interrupts may fire again, this is a stackoverflow waiting to happen, especially on unpredictable hardware interrupts.
Recommendation
When using interrupts, use the routine to enable a flag, which you then process in your event loop, often called "superloop".
volatile uint8_t flag = 0;

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
 flag = 1;
}

void main(){
  while(true){
    if(flag){
       flag = 0;
       // do menu
    }
  }
}

As you see this may quickly make the use for the ISR obsolete. You can also poll the pin directly in your superloop, with similar results if the superloop runs fast enough.
Or, perhaps the SoftwareSerial does not require this. I did not look into that. It may depend on timers and delays.

You are not telling which libraries you use but you need to know how the libraries you use work.
If this was Arduino Serial library, it would return immediately from the Send() method and use UART interrupts to send data out from a buffer.
Which it obviously cannot do since you are in an interrupt. OK, I guess your interrupt enables further interrupts, so the problem is likely that the LCD writing routine is not re-entrant.
You write to LCD in main code and in your interrupt.
You generaly don't do that. Simply make your main code aware that button is pressed and then hande the menu in main code.
There is no reason to do it against best practices when using external libraries you don't know how they work. If those are Arduino libraries, carefully read the documentation or actual source code how they can be used.
Calling any random external code from interrupts without knowing if you can even do that is just not a good idea.
You also disable further interrupts manually with SREG, but further interrupts are already disabled when entering an interrupt, so if you software depends on nested interrupts, you should enable them, not disable.
Also the I2C may run in the background using interrupts. Again, it's your responsibility to know what your libraries do and if they define how you should use them.
